# Вставка значений в бд с помощью php и js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, oracle

Изменил вопрос, добавив конкретики в виде кода.

Есть таблица со списком курсов и оценок. Напротив каждого курса есть кнопка `Send result`. По клику должна добавляться запись в бд с параметрами в запросе нужного курса и оценки.

**lib.php**

```
<html>
<head>

<script type = "text/javascript">
function sendResult() {
    if(confirm("Send result?")) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "checkquery.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function() {
                alert("Submitted!");
            }
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$link = '<a onclick = "return sendResult()" href = "..." target = "_blank">Send result</a>';
echo $link;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**checkquery.php**

```
$db = "...";

$conn = oci_connect($login, $pass, $db, "CL8MSWIN1251") or die("Error");

$query = "INSERT INTO...";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: Может можно, может нельзя - кто его знает... В коде который вы дали есть только какая-то функция, с каким-то условием, и каким-то циклом, внутри которого зачем-то происходит соединение с субд Oracle, да подготовка запроса вставки. И при этом вы фактически спрашиваете, можно ли в ваш движок интегрировать ajax-взаимодействие... По такому куску кода, на ваш вопрос сможет ответить только очень-очень сильный экстрасенс, да и то не факт.

Answer (score 1):

Очень сложно сказать по приведенному Вашему коду. Но Вы должны использовать XMLHttpRequest в JS (Ajax) следующим образом. 
У вас есть какой-то скрипт  for_ajax.php  , в котором принимаются данные с формы, инклудится Ваш файл lib.php и потом в нём вызывается метод fill_table. 
Соответственно, чтобы передать данные с формы в скрипт for_ajax.php , Вы можете изучить следующий материал: 
http://xmlhttprequest.ru

Думаю, что будет всё понятно